# Using "CSS-Grid", how do you deal with side margins without using Margin: auto;?

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a small project in which I need to create a responsive **"CSS - GRID"** layout for the mobile version of the project.

I noticed that apart from **margin: auto;** the only way to create borders is using 1fr units with a middle column of 20 or more FR.

Example: grid-template-columns: **1fr 20fr 1fr;** (This method makes the borders automatically disappear on the mobile devices).

I need to know, is there any better alternative way of doing this?

Comment: this method won't make the border disapear but very small

Comment: Actually, 1fr can sometimes equate to pretty much 0px depending on screen resolution of the device and what's in the middle content.

Comment: @FacundoCorradini (you might have deleted your comment as it has just disappeared. Regardless... the question sort of set me off at first too. But, I think I understand where he is coming from though... I think he means when it comes to responsive transitions (large margins on mobile devices look ugly) that's just my opinion though.

Comment: so... wouldn't max-width and margin auto on the grid container work?

Comment: In my experience they did... some think it's not a pure css grid approach, though. (Especially because the grid itself has a minmax directive.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's funny you are asking. I was *just thinking on this myself. In fact, I am tryig to come up with an optimal desktop -> mobile responsive transition. My very first approach was to simply use **margin: auto;** not surprisingly, it works just like it does on any other element:

[image]

That's your traditional setup. Same goes for CSS grid (Let's say your grid-template-columns is **1fr 800px 1fr**

[image]

Nothing's wrong with this desktop "middle column" setup. The problem arises, when you start scaling down to mobile devices and smart phones:

On mobile devices you no longer need a large side margin. So you are left with 1fr's right? My personal solution was to simply remove margin: auto and rely on 1fr for borders... but this only works when your middle column is set to something like 20/30fr, you have to play around with values intuitively to get the best results:

[image]

This seems to be the solution most people use. Grid is completely different way of thinking, you no longer think in "pixel-perfect" design, but think relative to other elements.

Other than this, I really can't think of anything else. I actually like 1fr borders, especially if they leave like 5-10 pixel margin, I think they make the page look better. But that's just an opinion of one man.

There is this [css grid article](https://semicolon.dev/tutorial/css/complete-css-flex-tutorial) floating around that helped me the most to get an idea of how this works. Hope it help. Cheers.